# Categorize down a column based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case, mutate

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
group1 <- c('A','A','A','A',
            'B','B','B','B',
            'C','C','C','C')

group2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4,
            1, 2, 3, 4,
            1, 2, 3, 4)


indicator <- c(1, 1, 1, 1,
               1, 1, NA, 1,
               NA, 1, 1, NA)


df <- data.frame(group1, group2, indicator)
```

I want to create a new column that evaluates the value of indicator for each group2 value within a value of group1 by the following logic:

```
(1) First value of 1 = "New"
(2) First value of 1 after NA = "Return"
(3) All other values of 1 = "Normal"
(4) All NAs = "None"
```

The resulting dataframe would like the following:

```
group1   group2    indicator    category
A        1         1            New
A        2         1            Normal
A        3         1            Normal
A        4         1            Normal
B        1         1            New
B        2         1            Normal
B        3         NA           None
B        4         1            Return
C        1         NA           None
C        2         1            New
C        3         1            Normal
C        4         NA           None
```

The evaluating down a column part of this is tripping me up. How should I go about producing the desired dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  
  mutate(category = ifelse(is.na(indicator), "None", "Normal"),
         
         category = case_when(cumsum(category != "None") == 1 ~ "New",
                              lag(category) == "None" ~ "Return",
                              .default = category),

         .by = group1)

#>    group1 group2 indicator category
#> 1       A      1         1      New
#> 2       A      2         1   Normal
#> 3       A      3         1   Normal
#> 4       A      4         1   Normal
#> 5       B      1         1      New
#> 6       B      2         1   Normal
#> 7       B      3        NA     None
#> 8       B      4         1   Return
#> 9       C      1        NA     None
#> 10      C      2         1      New
#> 11      C      3         1   Normal
#> 12      C      4        NA     None
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is .default = category the same as TRUE ~ category?

Comment: @user2813606 yes, it was introduced in `dplyr` version 1.1.0 with a note that the `TRUE ~` might eventually not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using some helper columns. I leave them in so you can understand what's going on, but you can of course drop them after the calculation is done:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, 
  na_counter = cumsum(is.na(indicator)),
  one_counter = cumsum(coalesce(indicator, 0) == 1),
  one_after_first_na_counter = cumsum(na_counter > 0 & coalesce(indicator, 0) == 1),
  category = case_when(
    is.na(indicator) ~ "None",
    one_counter == 1 ~ "New",
    one_after_first_na_counter == 1 ~ "Return",
    .default = "Normal"
  ),
  .by = group1
)
#    group1 group2 indicator na_counter one_counter one_after_first_na_counter category
# 1       A      1         1          0           1                          0      New
# 2       A      2         1          0           2                          0   Normal
# 3       A      3         1          0           3                          0   Normal
# 4       A      4         1          0           4                          0   Normal
# 5       B      1         1          0           1                          0      New
# 6       B      2         1          0           2                          0   Normal
# 7       B      3        NA          1           2                          0     None
# 8       B      4         1          1           3                          1   Return
# 9       C      1        NA          1           0                          0     None
# 10      C      2         1          1           1                          1      New
# 11      C      3         1          1           2                          2   Normal
# 12      C      4        NA          2           2                          2     None
```